# Unable to uninstall mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-22.04

Hi I've been having some problems lately with starting mysql in Ubuntu-22.04.
When i try `sudo service mysql start` an error pops up:

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.
```

I've also tried some "fixes" from stackoverflow and other forums but none of them seemed to work mainly because of the autoremove part.

```
root@server-HP-Z420-Workstation:~# apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is not about programming, so its not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling and installing the server like this:

1. sudo apt-get clean
2. sudo apt-get purge mysql*
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install -f
5. sudo apt-get install mysql-server-8.0

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`
The outcome is an error ( https://pastebin.com/XdPLap41 ) and therefore the installations also fail.

Comment: Try to install mysql again. Once successfully installed, try uninstall. It might work.

Comment: Tried to install, then it required me to fix broken install and then another error, https://pastebin.com/u0v4YQNb

Comment: The main problem is that when i try to do anything it always ends up failing to stop mysql.service, even when i manage to remove everything else except mysql-server (because it fails to remove)